# How to remove all strings from a list of tuples python

Tags: python, list, tuples

I am trying to remove all strings from a list of tuples

```
ListTuples = [(100, 'AAA'), (80, 'BBB'), (20, 'CCC'), (40, 'DDD'), (40, 'EEE')]
```

I have started to try and find a solution:

```
output = [i for i in ListTuples if i[0] == str]

print(output)
```

But I can't seem to get my head around how I would get an output like:

```
[(100), (80), (20), (40), (40)]
```

The format is always (`int`, `str`).

Comment: Do you know that you are always going to have items of the form `[(<int>, <str>), ...]`?

Comment: If the format is always (`int`, `str`) the following could be a simple solution: `output = [(i[0],) for i in ListTuples]`

Comment: @MarkNijboer Yes this is also perfect

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a nested tuple comprehension and `isinstance`:

```
output = [tuple(j for j in i if not isinstance(j, str)) for i in ListTuples]
```

Output:

```
[(100,), (80,), (20,), (40,), (40,)]
```

Note that there are trailing commas in the tuples to distinguish them from e.g. `(100)` which is identical to `100`.

Comment: This answer does no match OP's desired output!

Comment: @RoadRunner, Not true, `[(100), (80), (20), (40), (40)]` is valid Python, it's a list of integers!

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly! I just have to change the isinstance(j, str) to isinstance(j, int) to get the integer values I'm after. I will accept this answer

Comment: Having brackets only makes sense if it is a tuple. Otherwise it should simply be a list of ints. IMO tuples make more sense, as each original tuple could perhaps have more integers in them

Comment: I think this _does_ match OP's desired output, or rather what OP (probably) intended to show, not how that's interpreted by Python.

Comment: @jpp that's true but it wouldn't have been printed with the parentheses.

Comment: @a.rowland If you want to "remove all strings", then you should use `not isinstance(j, str)`, otherwise it would be "keep all integers", which is not strictly the same. (In your example, both would be equivalent, though.)

Answer (score 2):

Since extracting the first item of each tuple is sufficient, you can unpack and use a list comprehension. For a list of tuples:

```
res = [(value,) for value, _ in ListTuples]  # [(100,), (80,), (20,), (40,), (40,)]
```

If you need just a list of integers:

```
res = [value for value, _ in ListTuples]     # [100, 80, 20, 40, 40]
```

For a functional alternative to the latter, you can use [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter):

```
from operator import itemgetter
res = list(map(itemgetter(0), ListTuples))   # [100, 80, 20, 40, 40]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another solution using [`filter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter):

```
def non_string(x):
    return not isinstance(x, str)

print([tuple(filter(non_string, x)) for x in ListTuples])
# [(100,), (80,), (20,), (40,), (40,)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ListTuples = [(100, 'AAA'), (80, 'BBB'), (20, 'CCC'), (40, 'DDD'), (40, 'EEE')]

ListInt = []
ListStr = []

for item in ListTuples:
    strAux = ''
    intAux = ''
    for i in range(0, len(item)):

        if(isinstance(item[i], str)):
            strAux+=item[i] 
        else:
            intAux+=str(item[i])


    ListStr.append(strAux)
    ListInt.append(intAux)


print(ListStr)

'''TO CONVERT THE STR LIST TO AN INT LIST'''
output= list(map(int, ListInt)) 
print(output)
```

The output is `[100, 80, 20, 40, 40]`

Comment: What are those "aux" accumulators for? Why not directly `appen` in the `if/else`? This will fail for `[(1, "foo", 3)]` or any other tuple that has more than one of each type, and for any other cases those "aux" variables have no use, either.

Comment: If you `appen` in `if/else` it you retrieve `'A', 'A', 'A', 'B' 'B' ` and so on, because its inside `for loop`. If you try `[(1, "foo", 3)]`it will return `13` and `foo`

Comment: No, it does not, as you are not iterating the characters _in_ the string, just the elements in the tuple. And, yes, it will return _that_, and I don't think that that's what OP intended.

Answer (score 0):

We check if a particular value is a string or not using `type(value)`.

```
output = [tuple([j for j in i if type(j)!=str]) for i in ListTuples]
print(output)
    [(100,), (80,), (20,), (40,), (40,)]
```